# best practice to read inner static class and its vairables

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, struts, webservice-client

The below code is a web service response format.This class has two reference variables 
to two inner static class.
Please let me know how to read in an efficiant way.

```
public class DataResponse {
      protected DataResponse.Head head ;
      protected DataResponse.Result result ;

      public static class Result {
         protected List<DataResponse.Result.Record> record;

          public static class Record {
             protected String businesstypec;
             protected String part
             // several other variables

                 public static class PARTR {
                       protected String prefix;
                       protected String suffix;
                 }
          }

         public static class Head {

          // some more variables
         }

      // please assume getter and setters for head,result,record,prefix and suffix variables
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "read in an efficient way"?

Comment: @kirk Woll : question anticipated ...a simple or better way of reading above code....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the `instance` of `Record` you want to read and call the `public` `variable` of the `class` within to get the `instance` of that `variable` and then call the (again, `public`) `variables` in that inner class. Seems efficient.

```
 String firstPrefix = result.record.get(0).partrVariableThatsNotInYourExample.prefix;
```